# i want to add a dropdown to the top of my listview as a filter on the basis of one of my listview item

Tags: java, android, listview

Actually there are many tutorials telling how to add a editText at the top of listview as a filter but i need to create a drop down menu at the top of the listview in which one of the listview item will serve the filter.

Like in my project:

I have (LOCATION) as my listview item and i want to add this as a filter to my listview so that users can accordingly filter according to location nearby.

this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616475/android-listview-filtering-from-a-dropdown-menu-or-checkboxes) is same as mine but the answer is too confusing.

Also can anyone please help me to load all the locations in the dropdown which are coming from the server to the top of listview.

HERE IS THE CODE WHICH I ADDED TO SOLVE THE FILTER ISSUE BUT DIDN'T WORK AT ALL

```
private ArrayList<Food> filterFood = new ArrayList<Food>();

private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

    public Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}

private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

            results.values = food;
            results.count = food.size();
        }
        else {

            ArrayList<Food> filterFood = new ArrayList<Food>();

            for (Food txtPlace : food) {
                 if (txtPlace.getName().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                    filterFood.add(txtPlace);
            }

            results.values = filterFood;
            results.count = filterFood.size();

        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        if (filterResults.count == 0)
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        else {
            food = (ArrayList<Food>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

and i have added this to my get view method

```
final Food filteritem = filterFood.get(position);
    holder.txtPlace.setText(filteritem.txtPlace);
```

txtPlace is my listview item which should my filter of listview.

Can anybody help.

Thanks in Advance.